# Can not login, I am encountering login loop in Fedora 36 after changing /etc/profile file when adding flutter

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I was installing flutter and the I added the following line to `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
   PATH="..."
else
   PATH="/usr/local/bin:...:/etc/lib/flutter/bin"
fi
export PATH
```

This is exactly how I edited the file. Now I can't login terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>. Successful login in would give me a non functional bash.

Please note that I only appended this.

So my question is, does that mean my path reads `/usr/local/bin:...:/etc/lib/flutter/bin` and other directories are not in path. How can I edit the environmental variables?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU/SE. Please don't add additional info in the comments, that is not what they are for. Please [edit] your post and add info there. I have done that for you, this time. Thanks. Also, please take the [tour] to get a better understadning of how Stack Exchange works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem by using my ubuntu OS. While in Ubuntu I did the following :

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

I then explored to `/etc/` and opened the file `Profile` and removed the the codes I had added to the file and now I'm back into my Fedora 36 Workstation.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is still functional. You can either run commands via their actual paths:

```
$  /bin/sudo /bin/nano /etc/profile
```

*(Most programs are either in /bin or /usr/bin; in Fedora the two locations are equivalent.)*

or literally change `PATH=` at the shell the same way you're doing in /etc/profile:

```
$  PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH"
$  export PATH
$  sudo nano /etc/profile
```

In the tutorial that you were following, you were supposed to find the *existing* place where PATH= configuration was done in /etc/profile, i.e. the actual system paths should have been used instead of the literal `...`.

When *appending* new configuration to the file, you can use `$PATH` to refer to the current value, and only add the needed directories before/after. For example, the tutorial should probably have suggested this instead:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -ne 0 ]; then
    PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"
fi
export PATH
```

Comment: Thank you so much I now know how to edit the path based on your answer.